# Insert and return a new node to binary search tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I need to insert a new tree node to a binary search tree but also return the same node I inserted.
I've seen few examples of how to insert new node, but the return value is always the tree root and not the new node.

Thats what I've done so far, the main function is updateTree

```
typedef struct treeNode
{
    int data;
    struct treeNode* left;
    struct treeNode* right;
}TreeNode;

typedef struct tree
{
    TreeNode* root;
}Tree;


TreeNode* updateTree(Tree* tree, int data)
{
    if (tree->root == NULL)
    {
        tree->root = createNode(data);
        return tree->root;
    }
    else
    {
        return insertNode(tree->root, data);
    }
}

TreeNode* insertNode(TreeNode* root, int data)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return createNode(data);
    }
    else if (data > root->data)
    {
        root->right = insertNode(root->right, data);
    }
    else
    {
        root->left = insertNode(root->left, data);
    }
    return root;
}

TreeNode* createNode(int data)
{
    TreeNode* node;

    node = (TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    checkMemoryAllocation(node);

    node->data= data;

    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;

    return node;
}
```

My question is, how do I return the new node I created?

Comment: There is no question in your post. Ask a specific question.

Comment: when you create the root node you are not saving it. before returning **createNode(data)** you need to save it as root node so ***root = createNode(data)**

Comment: Please explain the `insertNode` function to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) in great detail. Especially what it returns.

Comment: Also, the whole update/insert logic seems off to me. I suggest you take a few steps back, get some paper and a pencil, and start drawing out the operations on paper before you reimplement them.

Comment: @EricPostpischil My question is how do I return the new node I created.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know the current issue is that I always return root, I couldn't figure out how to fix it though, I've tried multiple variations.
Also what exactly do you mean by 'logic seems off' ?

Comment: Have you tried e.g. `return root->right = insertNode(root->right, data);`? (And similarly for left)? It still doesn't "feel" right, but I haven't tried to debug it in any way.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not sure what your syntax means exactly, but I've tried


`root->right = insertNode(root->right, data);

return root->right;`
(not sure why the return isn't in a new line)

Comment: In C assignment is an expression, which gives a result. And like any other expression that gives a result, it can be used for the `return` statement. So for a simple example with `int a; int b = 2;` then `return a = b;`, `return (a = b);` and `a = b; return a;` are all equivalent.